# Get Random Functions from Main

Tags: java, function, program-entry-point

```
public static GetRandomFunc() {
    switch((int)(Math.random()*NUM_FUNCTIONS)  {
        case 0:
            functionA();
            break;
        case 1:
            functionB();
            break;
        case 2:
            functionC();
            break;
          //  ...
    }
}
```

I want to call GetRandomFunc() in main randomly until each function has been called once and then it ends. How do I make sure a function would be called once only, and if all has been called, it prints out System.out.println("All done")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a list containing 0,1 and 2. shuffle it and iterate over it to call each function once but in random order.

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(0,1,2);
Collections.shuffle(integers)
for (Integer i: integers){
   GetRandomFunc(i)
}
```

and your function will be

```
public static GetRandomFunc(int index) {
    switch(index)  {
        case 0:
            functionA();
            break;
        case 1:
            functionB();
            break;
        case 2:
            functionC();
            break;
          //  ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution for you. Don't overarchitect it by implementing an interface and multiple classes. This way you can keep your existing code in getRandomFunc and just add on top of it.

Comment: Hi,i am really new to java/programming. Could you explain a bit more. Do i create a new function for this? Or it is in the GetRandomFunc()?

Comment: And how do i pass the i as a parameter to GetRandomFunc(). Please elaborate more, I will be really grateful if you did. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the answer to have the new definition of the function. You need to pass the index to the function as it is determined out of it

Comment: The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
 <Integer>

Comment: It seems you imported java.awt.* and java thinks you are using java.awt.List. Use java.util.List instead which supports generic parameters

Comment: if (polarity.equals("_positive_") )

{
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(0,1,2);

Collections.shuffle(integers)

for (Integer i: integers){

GetRandomFunc(i)

}

Comment: this is my logic for calling the function, its suppose keep calling GetRandomFunc(i) from main if polarity is positive, until every function has been called then prints out "all done" , but it seems to call it only once then stops. Can you help please

Comment: if by once you mean it does not call all functions, I don't know why. May be you should create another question that elaborates the whole code.

Answer (score 3):

Make a list of the functions and take from it at random. When it's empty, you can be sure you used every function exactly once.

```
public interface Function { void execute(); }

public static runFunctionsRandomly(List<Function> functions) {
  while (!functions.isEmpty()) {
      int index = Math.random() * functions.size();
      Function f = functions.get(index);
      f.execute();
      functions.remove(index);
  }
}

class ExampleFunction implements Function {
  void execute() {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
  }
}
...
```

Comment: You cannot really create a list of functions in java (unless this is some interface)

Answer (score 3):

Use a list of `Runnable`s (or of Integers mapping to each function, as you did in your code), shuffle it, then iterate through the list and call each function.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29